# How to create a dataframe using arrays generated from a loop as columns in a dataframe

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array, multiple-columns

I have a loop printing out arrays of the form [[1,2,3,...100]] [[3,4,5, ...102]]and so on. I need each of the [[---]] to be a separate column in a dataframe. I tried to append them into a list but it is harder to add a 3D array to a dataframe. Could someone please suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
pd.DataFrame(np.array(a).transpose())
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

---

#### Per Comments below:

```
a = [np.array([[ 1,2,3]]), np.array([[3,4,5]])]

pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(a).T)
```

Comment: It gives this error: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input.

Comment: When it is in the form of an appended list, it looks like this: [array([[ 1,2,3]]), array([[3,4,5]])]